# Diacritic recognition in Handwritten Text Recognition

Tags: handwriting-recognition

I'm not really sure if this is the right site for asking this, but I've read so many papers about the handwriting recognition problem applied to different language scripts or languages.

However, I still don't have a clear understanding about recognizing diacritics (á, à, ä or ñ, ć, č). Are they recognized as full new characters?

Are the diacritics separated from the alphabet characters so that we can do character+diacritics combinations?

Thanks in advance!